# Coda function and class lookup

Tags: class, function, lookup, coda

I've googled around a little bit, and can't seem to find anything, but I've been developing front end stuff in Coda for a while now, but lately I've been getting into more sophisticated server-side scripting, and I'm now on a team building a product on a custom PHP framework.

I've used eclipse before, and one of the really handy features is that you can [cmd]+click function/class names, and the IDE will find the source for you. Is this possible in Coda/2, or is this one of the features that developers were looking for and didn't get when Coda2 came out?

Answer (score 0):

If you highlight and right-click on a function name, you can select '*Look Up In Reference Books*' and Coda will open a new tab with the appropriate book while profiling the search box to find the function you highlighted. If you don't have a book in your library for that framework or language, it may fail.

While there is no keyboard shortcut in Coda to do this, you can define one. In this article https://panic.com/blog/top-20-secrets-of-coda-2/ tip #20 shows you how to do it. Pay attention to the name of the reference book look up command as it has to be exactly the same spelling and letter casing.